# How do i get the url for an image from an object array

Tags: java, arrays, rss, feed

I'm getting a list of URLs from a feed, how do i get desired urlfrom the list.

I receive a list of URLs that i pass to an object, among these are url to an image it self, a thumbnail, information on type of file etc.

```
URL url = new URL("https://catalog.example.com/publicdomain/browse/en/recent.atom");
XmlReader xmlReader = null;

try {

  xmlReader = new XmlReader(url);
  SyndFeed feeder = new SyndFeedInput().build(xmlReader);

  for (Iterator iterator = feeder.getEntries().iterator(); iterator
      .hasNext();) {
    SyndEntry syndEntry = (SyndEntry) iterator.next();


    System.out.println(syndEntry.getAuthor());
    Object[] str = syndEntry.getLinks().toArray();

    System.out.println(str[3] );

  }
} finally {
      if (xmlReader != null)
        xmlReader.close();
}
```

When I use 'str[3]' the output is the following:

```
John Doe
SyndLinkImpl.hreflang=null
SyndLinkImpl.rel=http://opds-example.org/image/thumbnail
SyndLinkImpl.length=0
SyndLinkImpl.href=https://covers.example.net/book/6709.jpg
SyndLinkImpl.title=null
SyndLinkImpl.type=image/jpeg
```

I don;t want to put hardcode the index of the array because the feed can change.
How do i alter my code to detect which index of the array has a url for type image and copy the url.
I will like to use same approach to check which index has a url for content of type pdf.

Thamls

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it in the following way:

```
SyndFeed feeder = new SyndFeedInput().build(xmlReader);
for (SyndEntry syndEntry: feeder.getEntries()) {

    System.out.println(syndEntry.getAuthor());
    List<SyndLinkImpl> links = syndEntry.getLinks().stream().filter(link -> "image/jpeg".equals(link.getType))()).collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(links.toArray());
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Naya. i noticed an error with the brackets on the fourth line. Could you check that.